# Expiry Date of a European patent

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [EP1807053A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1807053A1)

What is the expiration date of this patent?

Answer (score 1):

According European Patent convention expiry of European patent if it is not withdrawn, abandoned, revoked or lapsed is 20 year from filing date; it can be extended by contracting state;

> Article 63[ 53 ] Term of the European patent
>
> Art. 2
>
> (1) The term of the European patent shall be **20 years from the date of
> filing of the application.**
>
> (2) Nothing in the preceding paragraph
> shall limit the right of a Contracting State to extend the term of a
> European patent, or to grant corresponding protection which follows
> immediately on expiry of the term of the patent, under the same
> conditions as those applying to national patents:

European patent status can be quickly seen at EPO register. through direct link given on Google Patents (see below image); or by using search page [European Patent Register](https://register.epo.org/regviewer)

Form example query application was withdrawn hence not active.

[image]